# Approval levels for retainers and allies in NWOD venues

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-1e, vampire-the-requiem, the-camarilla-minds-eye-society

1.) Does anyone know what kind of level of approval a person would need to have a vampire as their retainer?

2.) Does anyone know what kind of level of approval a person would need to have a Vampire Hunter as an ally?

Comment: Just to be clear: we're talking about MES approvals here, for the Requiem venue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This information is available in [the latest version of the MES addendum](http://www.mindseyesociety.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/MESUniversalAddendum-May20131.pdf). In the Universal document, it says,

> **U.VIII.E.3**: Retainers can have lesser templates specific to the character's venue (e.g. ghouls in Requiem, sleepwalker in Awakening, etc.) at Low Approval and supernatural templates at High Approval.
>
> **U.VIII.E.4**: Retainers cannot be any kind of supernatural creature from another venue unless specifically allowed in this supplement.

So the answers to your questions are:

1. High Approval. (RST)
2. If it's just an ordinary Vampire Hunter, Low Approval, although I might consult your DST as well. If it's one of the Hunters from the *Vigil* books, then it's Not Allowed.